# How do I create a loop with multiple if criteria across dataframe columns?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe with several column variables and around 10 rows of replicates, and a second dataframe with the same variables but 700 rows. I want to create a loop that takes each value of the row in the second dataframe and see if it falls within the range of the corresponding column of the first dataframe. So far I have tried a rather inelegant long `for loop` with so many syntax errors that I can't work out where to start fixing it.

Here is a shortened version of my dataframes. Dataframe 1: c1a

```
WAV    UV     VIOLET    BLUE
2D1    10.8   10.1      23.5
3A4    6.2    8.2       19.9
4A1    8.3    11.7      28.6
5C2    7.9    8.2       31.0
5C3    10.7   9.5       18.1
```

Dataframe 2: paint2

```
ID    UV     VIOLET    BLUE
D1    7.9    10.1      19.3
D2    7.0    9.2      15.9
D3    21.4   20.7      27.4
D4    10.3   8.9      20.9
D5    21.7   16.5      21.3
```

So what I want is to see if each of the values for D1 fall into the ranges of the corresponding columns of dataframe 1 and so on for each row, and then get an output of which IDs all columns were successful for.

My code:

```
c1a.out=NULL

for (i in nrow(paint2)){
  if (min(c1a[,2]) < [i,2] < max(c1a[,2])
  && min(c1a[,3]) < [i,3] < max(c1a[,3])
  && min(c1a[,4]) < [i,4] < max(c1a[,4])){
  c1a.out=c(c1a.out, [i,1])
  }
}
```

The output would just be a list of which ID names have values that fall into the range of the entire COLUMN in the first dataframe.

```
>c1a.out
>D1  D4
```

For example, D2 doesn't make the list because its BLUE value isn't in the range of BLUE values in c1a, even though its UV and VIOLET values are in the range for their respective columns in c1a.

I know it's ugly, I don't know much about making loops. 
If there is a correction for the errors I'm receiving (unexpected brackets and commas), or a simpler and more elegant version of my loop that could be created, I'm all ears.

Comment: Are there supposed to be multiple values per ID in `c1a`? else the `min` and `max` make little sense. A fully reproducible example including desired output would be very helpful.

Comment: No, I want each value from the ID row to be tested within the entire column of the same variable in c1a. So I want to see if the value of UV for D1 is in the range of the c1a UV column, and repeating this for each column. And then looping this over each row. The output is simply a list of which rows (ID) have all of their values that fall in the range of the corresponding columns of c1a. Sorry, I'm finding this difficult to explain. I'll add some details to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a `tidyverse` solution, but perhaps a little more convoluted than I'd like - not obviously easier to read than the for loop. However, it should work for any number of variables to compare on, assuming all of the tables have the same structure of one ID column and then the same number of columns to compare on. I'll walk through the approach.

1. What we want to do is to compare each value in `paint2` to the correct values in `c1a`, and return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So we use `map2` to map through the columns in `paint2` except the first one (`.x = .[, -1]`) and the right indices of `c1a` (`.y = 2:ncol(.)`) in parallel. We can do this because dataframes are just lists of columns! So that whole `map2` line makes a new list with element per variable column, each element containing the right logical value. Like this:

One value per cell in `paint2`

```
$UV
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

$VIOLET
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

$BLUE
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

2. Then we want to compare each row and only return `TRUE` if every one is `TRUE`. So we first have to `transpose()`, so that each element is a row instead of a column.
3. Then, we want to check all the rows to see if they are all `TRUE`, so we map through the rows with `all`. The `unlist` is just to avoid a warning about using `all` on a list rather than a vector. That gives us:

One value per row in `paint2`

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

4. Lastly, we just use `which` to get the indices that are `TRUE`, and print out those values of `ID`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
c1a <- read_table2(
  "WAV    UV     VIOLET    BLUE
  D1    10.8   10.1      23.5
  A4    6.2    8.2       19.9
  A1    8.3    11.7      28.6
  C2    7.9    8.2       31.0
  C3    10.7   9.5       18.1"
)

paint2 <- read_table2(
  "ID    UV     VIOLET    BLUE
  D1    7.9    10.1      19.3
  D2    7.0    9.2      15.9
  D3    21.4   20.7      27.4
  D4    10.3   8.9      20.9
  D5    21.7   16.5      21.3"
)

indices <- paint2 %>% map2(
  .x = .[, -1],
  .y = 2:ncol(.),
  .f = ~ between(.x, min(c1a[, .y]), max(c1a[, .y]))
) %>%
  transpose() %>%
  map_lgl(~ all(unlist(., use.names = FALSE))) %>%
  which()

paint2$ID[indices]
#> [1] "D1" "D4"
```

Created on 2018-03-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

For further reading, [this is a great tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/) on `purrr` and using it to map through objects, avoiding `for` loops as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks so much, this has worked for me on my large dataset.